# PHP check atleast two buttons are selected

Tags: php

I've a form that will require user to choose/click at least two buttons in order to submit the form

```
<button type="button" name="Investor-agree-one">I AGREE</button>
<button type="button" name="Investor-agree-two">I AGREE</button>
<button type="button" name="Investor-agree-three">I AGREE</button>
<button type="button" name="Investor-agree-four">I AGREE</button>
<button type="button" name="Investor-agree-five">I AGREE</button>
```

How do I validate the form using php that at least two buttons are selected and redirect user to one page, if not redirect to another page? So basically is like:

```
if(buttonSelected>=2){
    goto this page
}else{
    goto another page
    }
```

How do I indicate whether the button is being selected in the first place using the button elements?

Comment: You can't check this BEFORE the form is submitted using php, only AFTER. If you want to check it before you have to use javascript

Comment: To check it before sending you should rather use javascript or jQuery

Comment: @Bowdzone, sorry that I didn't make myself clear. I've updated my question above. It is actually after user submission which mean I will need to use php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats pretty easy,

Give your buttons all the same "name", and a unique value
so lets say we have this button tag:

```
<form method="post">
<button name="somebutton" value="buttonone">
<button name="somebutton" value="buttontwo>
<button name="somebutton" value="buttontwo">
</form>
```

Your php should then look something like this:

```
<?php
$button = $_POST['somebutton'];
if($button == "buttonone"){
    //do button 1 stuff, in your example:
    header('location: someurl.php');
}
if($button == "buttontwo"){
    // do button 2 stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry that I didn't make myself clear. I've updated my question above. It is actually after user submission which mean I will need to use php

Comment: updating awnser, hold on ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may use checkbox instead of button, so your code may like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['agree_one'])) {
        // do something
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree_one" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree_two" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree_three" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
</form>
```

But if you just want to count how much user has selected the agree checkbox, you may want this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['agree']) && count($_POST['agree']) > 2) {
    // do magic
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree[]" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree[]" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree[]" value="1"/>
        I Agree
    </label>
</form>
```